# sh command giving "[[: not found " error when I am running through Jenkins stage

Tags: linux, jenkins, kubernetes

In this Jenkin stage, I am trying to get the pod status and if the status is "TRUE" it will move to the next stage else wait for it.

```
      node('master'){
           withEnv(["KUBECONFIG=${JENKINS_HOME}/.kube/config"]){
                POSTGRES_CMD= """while [[ \$(kubectl get  pods -l app=postgres-${NAME_SPACE} -o 'jsonpath={..status.conditions[?(@.type=="Ready")].status}' -n ${NAME_SPACE}) != "True" ]]; do echo "waiting for pod" && sleep 1;done"""
                echo "${POSTGRES_CMD}"
                READY_POD = sh (
                        script: "${POSTGRES_CMD}",
                        returnStdout: true
                  ).trim()
                 echo "${READY_POD}"
```

```
Error:- /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/k8s@2@tmp/durable-95fdd/script.sh: [[: not found
```

Comment: Sounds like you're using `sh` instead of `bash` or another shell that understands `[[`.

Comment: any alternate way how to handle this in the jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POSIX `sh` supports single bracket conditionals: `[]`. You should be fine using `$()` for command substitution, in some environment you might need to use back ticks `

```
while [ "`echo \"true\"`" == "true" ]; do
  sleep 1
done
```

In any case, `kubectl` supports running that wait loop for you:

```
kubectl wait pods --for=condition=Ready -l app=postgres-${NAME_SPACE} -n ${NAMESPACE} --timeout=60s
```

Comment: means, You are saying I can use "kubectl wait pods .." for my Jenkins stage "postgres pod to become ready" ?

Comment: Yes, for `POSTGRES_CMD` instead of the `whlie` loop

Answer (score 0):

That’s a bash feature. Most small container images use busybox or similar which is sh but not bash.

Comment: any alternate way how to handle this in the jenkinsfile?

Comment: Use [ instead, that’s the sh version

Comment: only single [ is not solving my problem. Please check the command

Answer (score 0):

Just set `/bin/bash` setting in `Jenkins`->`Manage Jenkins`->`System`->`Shell`.

Jenkins uses `sh` by default instead of `bash`. `sh` does not support `[[` feature.